# apex:param not working, Values are not passing to apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

The apex:param is not passing the contact value to backend. Please correct me where i am going wrong.

```
 <apex:pageblocktable value="{!lstWrapContactRoles}" var="cr" id="pbt" >
                <apex:column headerValue="Contact">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!cr.objConRole.Contact__c}" onchange="if(this.value){addfunc();}" id="conId"> <!-- US 410 -->
                      <apex:param name="personID" value="{!cr.objConRole.Contact__c}" assignTo="{!Contactid}" />
                    </apex:inputfield>
                </apex:column>


        <apex:actionfunction name="addfunc" action="{!addNew}" reRender="pbt" oncomplete="codeAddress();checkboxuse();"/>
```

Apex:

```
public Id Contactid {get; set;}


  Public vooid addnew(){
system.debug('=='+System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('personID'));
    system.debug('strContactid'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Contactid')); 

}
```

Both the debugs are null.

Answer (score 2):

You have few things wrong here. From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm):

> The `<apex:param>` component can only be a child of the following components:
>
> - `<apex:actionFunction>`
> - `<apex:actionSupport>`
> - `<apex:commandLink>`
> - `<apex:outputLink>`
> - `<apex:outputText>`
> - `<flow:interview>`

Whereas, you are using `<apex:param>` as a child for `<apex:inputField>`.

Then, you access the values of the param that has been set using the `assignTo` using getter/setter method, whereas you are trying to access it from a request attribute on the page.

---

You'll need to review your implementation as what you are trying to achieve, but a typical implementation will look like as:

```
<apex:actionFunction>    
    <apex:param name="personID" value="{!cr.objConRole.Contact__c}" assignTo="{!ContactId}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

and then in the Apex, you access it as:

```
public Id ContactId {get; set;}

public void addnew(){
    // just use the variable as declared in the class here        
    system.debug('Contact Id assigned is:' + ContactId); 
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the snippet jayant

Comment: You will need to first change the implementation to correctly use `<apex:param>` (it cannot be a child of `<apex:inputField>`, and then access the value in apex by just using `ContactId`.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the sample snippet. But you will still need to review your implementation as what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: <apex:actionFunction> may not be used within an iterable component. You can use <apex:param> to define parameters for the function and pass iteration-specific values via the parameters. *This is the error I am getting*

Comment: Arvind - it's just a sample. As mentioned you will need to go through the details as what you are trying to achieve. I will recommend to first evaluate your use case here, and then go through some [VF trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals) and [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm) for more details. As the error says, you cannot use `<apex:actionFunction>` within a loop, so you need to revisit the scenario.

Comment: N.B. You can also make `apex:param` a child of `apex:commandButton` if you use `rerender=` (undocumented but a known workaround) - that said, I agree 100% with the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The apex:param must be a child of the action function.

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!cr.objConRole.Contact__c}" onchange="if(this.value){addfunc('{!cr.objConRole.Contact__c}');}" id="conId">
```

...

```
<apex:actionfunction name="addfunc" action="{!addNew}" reRender="pbt" oncomplete="codeAddress();checkboxuse();">
  <apex:param name="personID" value="" assignTo="{!Contactid}" />
</apex:actionfunction>
```

Comment: Brain I am still getting null values in my debug.
Any solution

Comment: @Arvind assignTo means you have a variable. Try `System.debug(ContactId);` instead.

Comment: @Arvind Actually, you're going to have other complications, because you won't get an ID here, but instead a string (e.g. John Doe instead of 003000xxxxxxxxx). This might be the most complicated method of whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah I still get all the values as Null. How can i get the Id in the same method .

Comment: @Arvind you'll have better luck with `apex:actionSupport`, instead. You're basically using the wrong tool for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I am insisted to use function and not support. and ID is very much required now to make further operations ..

Comment: @Arvind Lookup fields have hidden related input values. You would need to perform some arcane document.querySelector or jQuery selectors to get the ID value; and this would further be subject to breaking in future releases. Look at the page's source code to figure out what's going on. Function isn't the right way to go here.

Comment: If that is the case Can I use it inside the Pageblocktable?

Comment: @Arvind Yes, you can use actionSupport almost anywhere.